# Consultas anidadas en Django

Tags: python, django

Buenas tardes necesito un ejemplo de consultas anidadas en Django 1.11 usando `OuterRef(OuterRef('pk'))`

Gracias de ante manos

Comment: Hola Edilmerio, bienvenido a SOes. Te sugiero que realizes el [tour] para entender el funcionamiento del sitio y te informes sobre [ask] para realizar preguntas de mayor calidad. ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta con lo que has intentado y que es lo que quieres conseguir?

Comment: Aquí hay varios ejemplos: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Es como cualquier otra función, las consultas regresan Objetos y/o colecciones (Listas,diccionarios...) para después de ser manipuladas.

Un ejemplo que puedo darte es esta:

```
consulta_total = Augment_Skill.objects.all().filter(type=Augment_Type.objects.get(id=1))
```

`consulta_total` es la **variable** donde alojaré la consulta anidada después de ser llamada.

`Augment_Type.objects.get(id=1)` Esto en sí es una consulta; le estoy diciendo que me traiga el Objeto con id **1** de la tabla `Augment_Type`

Esa consulta está metida dentro de:

```
Augment_Skill.objects.all().filter(type=/* CONSULTA_INTERNA */)
```

Django ofrece de manera *implicita* estas consultas pero eso es otro tema.

Espero haber sido claro.